# TFS: Migrate from MSF Agile 5.0 to MS Scrum 1.0

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfsintegrationplatform

How do you do that? Any configuration templates for TFS Integration Tool or a specific tool to do the task?

Comment: Did you ever find a template for this?

Comment: see comment below answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/08/18/tfs-integration-tools-platform-the-world-of-tfs-project-template-agile-scrum-migrations-part-3.aspx) for some sample templates for Process Template Migrations.

Comment: yes got that... My question is: are there any configurations for the specific migration path indicated ind the title? (or any other valid migration path) I've read through the others and are working on my own config for now. Would have been nice if there were an official one for that transformation as I think the release of the Scrum 1.0 template will cause many to wanting to "upgrade" to the new template...

Comment: I need to do the same migration, did you get anywhere with this? Are you able to post your config?

Comment: I did not get a config and never godt to finish one my self - ended up recreating the project